# What is the logic behind the arrow function behaves differently when taking values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some questions about arrow function expression in JSX.
Here is an example code that updates the `content` when `onClick` happens.

```
const App = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('click here');
  const mouseOnClick = () => {
    setContent('clicked');
  };
  return <h1 onClick={mouseOnClick}>{content}</h1>
}
```

Then I tried different expressions to see how it behaves

```
1. onClick={()=>mouseOnClick}
// does not fire

2. onClick={mouseOnClick()} 
// Infinitely renders

3. onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}
// same as onClick={mouseOnClick}
```

However, when the function takes values, the expression behaves differently than my expectation.

```
1. onClick={()=>mouseOnClick(id)}
// works as expected

2. onClick={mouseOnClick(id)} 
// Infinitely renders
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the logic behind `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick}` not firing but `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}` does?
2. Why `onClick={mouseOnClick}` fires one time when `onClick={mouseOnClick(id)}` fires infinitely?
3. Are `onClick={mouseOnClick}` and `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}`
   functionally identical?

Comment: mouseOnClick(id) is being executed immediately and the result passed as onClick's function to call.  The others pass a function for onClick to call.

Comment: React has wrapper to all events called `SyntheticEvent` and for purposes of performance they recommended pass handler instead of function expression.
So you should have used `onClick={mouseOnClick}` instead of `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}`. But case which you've described in secound question:  `onClick={mouseOnClick(id)}` is using with hight-order functions.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a JSX issue. This is an issue of understanding of what a *function value* is and what a *function call* is.

**What is a function value?**

In JavaScript a function is a value like any other value. Just like `"foo"` creates a string value, `() => {}` creates a function value (more specifically, a function *object*; also note that this is same for any way to generate a function: function declaration, function expression, method declaration, arrow function ... all these are just various ways to indicate the creation of a function object).

In your example, `mouseOnClick` is a variable that holds a function. Whenever you write `mouseOnClick`, you referring/accessing that function object. Note that referring to the function object does not call the function! (see next section). Consider this example:

```js
var foo = () => console.log('foo')
var bar = foo;
```

Here I am assigning the value of `foo` (a function) to `bar`. The function itself is not executed in that process. The same happens when you pass a function as a parameter to another function:

```js
var foo = () => console.log('foo')
// Some hypothetical function bar
bar(foo)
```

In this example `bar` is called and the value of `foo` (a function) is passed to it. But the function in `foo` is not called.

**What is a function call?**

In order to invoke a function (value), you put `()` after it:

```js
var foo = () => 42;

console.log(foo); // logs function object
console.log(foo()); // calls function and logs its return value
```

Of course you can pass arguments to functions by putting them in between the `()`.

**How does `onClick` work?**

This works similar to all event handling APIs: `onClick` expects to be passed a function *value*, which can then call whenever the event occurs.

---

So with that said, lets look at your example:

> 1. `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick}`

This passes a function value to `onClick` (good). What does the function do? It simply references `mouseOnClick` (bad). We know that referencing a function doesn't actually call the function.

> 2. `onClick={mouseOnClick()}`

This calls the function (`()` after function name) and passes its return value to `onClick` (bad). We want to call `mouseOnClick` when the event happens not when the component is rendered.

> 3. `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}`

This passes a function value to `onClick` (good). What does the function do? It calls  `mouseOnClick` (good).

Now you are saying that the functions/syntax would behave differently if an argument is passed to it. But that's not actually the case:

> 4. `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick(id)}`

That's the same as case 3, just with argument.

> 5. `onClick={mouseOnClick(id)}`

That's the same as case 2, just with argument.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to pass to onClick prop is the callback function which will be called after `onClick` event. The `()` behind the function means that it will be called. So:

1. `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick}` Here you are creating new function which will return `mouseOnClick` function definition. there is no `()` so it won't run.
2. `onClick={mouseOnClick}` this is the correct way of passing a callback without parameters. You just passed a function which have to run after event. `{mouseOnClick(id)}` fires infinitely, because there are parenthesis after function - witch mean it will be auto-called when your element renders, your function is changing the state which is causing rerender - infinite rerendering.
3. Basicly they are but this one: `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}` is creating new function all the time, while `onClick={mouseOnClick}` is just pointing to one function.

Hope it was pretty clear and it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing to onClick not a function but a result from a function (you are calling the function inside { } brackets)

```
2. onClick={mouseOnClick(id)}
```

And here you are passing a reference to a function

```
onClick={mouseOnClick} and onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}
```

React expects to receive a function that will be callend when click event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of JSX you're mixing up callbacks and return values

lets say that this is your callback function

```
function func(arg) {
    return arg * 2;
}
```

If you were to pass the function like this it would execute it immediately and pass the return value to the onClick event

```
<h1 onClick={func()}>{content}</h1>
```

If you wrap this inside an arrow function it will wait with executing until the onClick event is triggered

```
<h1 onClick={()=>{func()}}>{content}</h1>
```

If you only pass the function name it will wait with executing it until the onClick is triggered and pass the event to it as well

```
<h1 onClick={func}>{content}</h1>
```

If you want to pass an argument to your function you either have to wrap it in an arrow function like so

```
<h1 onClick={() => {func(arg)}}>{content}</h1>
```

or don't pass it at all and create / reference it inside the function

```
function func() {
    let arg = retrieveValueFromSomething();
    return arg * 2;
}
<h1 onClick={func}>{content}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Q. What is the logic behind onClick={()=>mouseOnClick} not firing but onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()} does?

Ans. `()=>mouseOnClick` is denoting a function where you are returning `mouseOnClick`. This type of return is called implicit return. This expression is not working intentionally because function logic never got called. But `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}` is actually firing the function and thats why it works.

Q. Why onClick={mouseOnClick} fires one time when onClick={mouseOnClick(id)} fires infinitely?

Ans. `onClick` tries to call a function with click event. `mouseOnClick` is just that function. But when you say `onClick={mouseOnClick()}`, you just called the function on first render. If onclick is triggering state change, then another render will occur, and onclick will get called again. Hence infinite loop as mouseOnClick and render keep calling each other again and again.

Q. Are onClick={mouseOnClick} and onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()} functionally identical ?

Ans. Logically yes. but when you say `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}` then new function is being assigned to onClick on every render, which essentially keeps calls `mouseOnClick`. In another case, that is not true i.e. on every render onClick will remain same. This might impact performance sometime when you are sending inline function to props and that might result in unnecessary rendering of child because it will keep getting new function on every parent render.

Answer (score 0):

One is calling mouseOnClick and passing the return value to onClick.  So onClick=undefined or whatever mouseOnClick returns.
The other is passing mouseOnClick as a function to onClick.  So it calls mouseOnClick normally.

```js
function mouseOnClick () {
  console.log("mouseOnClick called");
  return fn2;
}

function fn2 () {
  console.log("fn2 called");
}

function fn3 () {
  console.log('btn2.onclick === fn2', btn2.onclick === fn2);
  console.log('btn1.onclick === mouseOnClick', btn1.onclick === mouseOnClick);
}


btn1.onclick = mouseOnClick;   // onclick = fn1
btn2.onclick = mouseOnClick(); // fn1 => fn2, so onclick = fn2
// notice "fn1 called" in console.  it is called immediately and passed to btn2.onclick

btn3.onclick = fn3;
```

```html
<button id="btn1">button</button>
<button id="btn2">button</button>

<button id="btn3">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you define a new anonymous function and pass it as the onClick handler. The function itself does nothing 'cause inside of it you don't call anything.

In the second case you are updating the state **during render** when you call mouseOnClick(id), which triggers the **re-render** so you get into an **infinite loop**.

In the third case you're just using a wrapper function that calls your mouseOnClick function, which is somewhat equivalent of calling the function itself as a handler.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at all the three cases individually -:

> - What is the logic behind onClick={()=>mouseOnClick} not firing but
>     onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()} does?
>
>   - It's ES5 translation is. -:
>
>     - `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick} === onClick={ function () { return mouseOnClick }}`
>     - `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick} === onClick={ function () { return mouseOnClick() }}`
>   - The first case is a simple function that returns a function reference.
>   - Since the first case only returns the function reference and doesn't call any function so no function call happens whereas in the
>       second case the function is actually called.

---

> - Why onClick={mouseOnClick} fires one time when    onClick={mouseOnClick(id)} fires infinitely?
>
>   - Translation for both case (what will both the cases return to the onClick) -:
>
>     - `onClick={mouseOnClick} === onClick={() => {
>         setContent('clicked')}`
>     - `onClick={mouseOnClick(id)} === onClick={mouseOnClick(id)} (direct function call)`.
>   - As we see the first case return a function whereas the second case returns direct function call so it gets called infinitely.

---

> - Are onClick={mouseOnClick} and onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()}    functionally identical?
>
>   - Yes both are identical let's see what they translate to -:
>
>     - `onClick={mouseOnClick} === onClick={() => {
>         setContent('clicked')}`
>     - `onClick={()=>mouseOnClick()} === onClick={// basically another function that calls mouseOnClick function }`

Hope that helps...